# FCM how to display data from notification click in another activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application that receive FCM notification, I want to display the content of notification and data payload in another activity, my challenge is when I click notification, it direct me to the desire activity but I don't get the information displayed.

Please help, the following is my code

```
MyFirebaseMessagingService
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        //you can get your text message here.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                String storedData = remoteMessage.getData().toString();
              //  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(storedData);

                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(storedData);
                JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
                String title = jObj.getString("title");
                String message = jObj.getString("body");
                sendPushNotification(jObj);

                final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyFCMFile";
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("Title", title);
                editor.putString("Message", message);
                editor.apply();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else {

            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
            Intent intent = new Intent(click_action);
            intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyFCMFile";
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("Title", title);
            editor.putString("Message", message);
            editor.apply();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());


        }
    }

    //this method will display the notification
    //We are passing the JSONObject that is received from
    //firebase cloud messaging
    private void sendPushNotification(JSONObject json) {
        //optionally we can display the json into log
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification JSON " + json.toString());
        try {
            //getting the json data
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            //parsing json data
            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            String imageUrl = data.getString("image");

            final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyFCMFile";

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("Title", title);
            editor.putString("Message", message);
            editor.apply();

            //creating MyNotificationManager object
            MyNotificationManager mNotificationManager = new MyNotificationManager(getApplicationContext());
            // CREATE CLICK ACTION

            //creating an intent for the notification

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notifications.class);

            //if there is no image
            if (imageUrl.equals("null")) {
                //displaying small notification
                mNotificationManager.showSmallNotification(title, message, intent);
            } else {
                //if there is an image
                //displaying a big notification
                mNotificationManager.showBigNotification(title, message, imageUrl, intent);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

my desire activityto display notification and data payload info -activity_notifications.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.Notifications">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="551dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
      >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/job_notificatication" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/my_border"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="JOB INFO"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Job Category :"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/category"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="36sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Job Type:"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/type"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="36sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Job Details:"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="36sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/my_border"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="CUSTOMER INFO"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Name :"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                     />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="36sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Address:"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/address"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="36sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Landmark"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/landmark"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="36sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Contact Person:"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/contact_person"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="36sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Expected Date"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/date"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="36sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Expected Time:"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/time"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="36sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/accept"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ACCEPT"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the Notifications.java

```
package com.example.workman;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Notifications extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView title, message;

    String txtTitle, txtMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifications);

        title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.category);
        message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.type);




    final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyFCMFile";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String txtTitle = prefs.getString("Title", "");//"No name defined" is the default value.
    String txtMessage = prefs.getString("Message", "");//"No name defined" is the default value.

        title.setText(txtTitle);
        message.setText(txtMessage);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the FCM documentation it appears you are doing it the wrong way.

`onMessageReceived()` would only be called if the app is already running in the foreground.

Otherwise, Android will display the notification (using the properties of the "notification" dictionary) and use the `getClickAction()` value to open the desired `Activity` without you having to write any code.

And you can obtain the "data" payload via the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

i.e. in your `Notifications` class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent ().getExtras (); // you should find the data here
    ...
}
```

Here's what worked for me:

In my second `Activity` class (the one that should be opened when the notification is clicked) I put :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    TextView text    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data2);
    if (text != null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent ().getExtras ();
        StringBuilder keys = new StringBuilder();
        if (extras != null) {
            for (String key : extras.keySet())
                keys.append(key + " = " + extras.getString(key) + "\n ");
        }
        text.setText("extras on second activity: " + keys.toString());
    }
}
```

I got the following output:

```
extras on second activity: google.sent_time = null
msg - some value (this is a key/value pair I included in the "data" dictionary)
uri - some value (this is a key/value pair I included in the "data" dictionary)
from - <the sender id>
google.message_id - <the message id returned in the receipt of the HTTP response>
collapse_key - com.package.fcmdemo (default value)
```

As you can see, the properties of my (custom) "data" dictionary were all passed to the activity. The properties of the "notification" dictionary were not passed, but I'm assuming that's intentional (since they were already used to display the notification I clicked in order to open the activity).

Comment: how do I fetch each value in the key value pairs?

Comment: @LaideLawal `extras.getString(key)`, as I wrote in my code sample.